# Swift getting error while upload base64 to server?

Tags: ios, swift, base64

My scenario, I am trying to upload the user `camera` and `photolibrary` captured image to my `server`. Here, Already we are sending few `parameters` like `(name, phone number, etc…)` within this we are added photo `parameter` and sending `base64` image data to the server. Now, while sending the `base64` strings to the server I am getting below error.

**My Error**

> 2019-03-08 17:49:52.872545+0530 myapp[441:40026] [BoringSSL]
>   nw_protocol_boringssl_error(1584) [C3.1:2][0x12dfd9e80] Lower protocol
>   stack error: 54 2019-03-08 17:49:52.873175+0530 myapp[441:40026] TIC
>   Read Status [3:0x280be5140]: 1:54 2019-03-08 17:49:52.877753+0530
>   myapp[441:40026] Task .<4> HTTP
>   load failed (error code: -1005 [4:-4]) 2019-03-08 17:49:52.878073+0530
>   myapp[441:40125] Task .<4>
>   finished with error - code: -1005

**I am using below code for JSON**

```
 apiPath = “https://.........com?country=\(get_countryID ?? "unknown")&last_update_date=\(today_string)&device_id=\(deviceID)&app_type=1&location=\(get_latlong)&photo=\(get_photobase64)”

         if let encodeString = apiPath.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed),
            let url = URL(string: encodeString) {
            let session = URLSession.shared
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            request.addValue(access_key, forHTTPHeaderField: "access-key")
            request.addValue(auth_token!, forHTTPHeaderField: "auth-token")
            request.timeoutInterval = 10
```

I gave already `Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES`.

Comment: Showing only a dozen lines of code won't tell the whole picture.  And what does "to upload user camera" mean?

Comment: Does the server have to recieve the data encoded to base 64? Many times you only have to send just the binary data in the body of the request, which would be simpler.

Comment: -1005 is supposed to mean "connection lost".  What does the server log say?  Did it see your request or did it close the connection?

Comment: Why are you sending your base64 string as URL parameter if you are using a POST? I assume you are exceeding the limits for the url length.
Send the base64 string (or even better: binary data) as part of the body where it should be.

Comment: @MartinM...Yes Your right I am sending huge base64 data string via POST call...My question how to reduce the string and how to pass it is within params.